# How to transition after hovering off in which animation is used in hovering

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, transition

I'm animating a text from 0 to 100px in X axis inside a div on hovering.The problem is when I hover off the div the animation snaps back very quickly. I need a transition effect to look good. Please help me out. Thanks

I tried applying transition on the normal state of the div and hovering state of the div but nothing worked

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: use some javascript to listen to the mouse leave, then just swap the class to a new class which matches the same but has the animation flipped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in only css, but recommend to use javascript, as when the page is it does animate full and then closed, then works as normal when hovering, i did force the width to start and end at 10px else you cannot hover over it.

```css
div.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
}

div.child {
  height: 64px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  animation-name: htz; /* Default animation for non-hover state */
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div.child:hover {
  animation-name: zth; /* Override animation for hover state */
}

@keyframes zth {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes htz {
  from {
    width: 100%;
  }
  to {
    width: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```